# Регулярное выражение для отбора алфавитных последовательностей без пропусков

Tags: регулярные-выражения, grep

Надо написать команду для терминала, используя grep или sed. Она должна выводить только подошедшие куски из текстового файла (без разницы в строку или в столбик). Perl юзать нельзя.

Сейчас есть такое регулярное выржение

```
a?\s*b?\s*c?\s*d?\s*e?\s*f?\s*g?\s*h?\s*i?\s*j?\s*k?\s*l?\s*m?\s*n?\s*o?\s*p?\s*q?\s*r?\s*s?\s*t?\s*u?\s*v?\s*w?\s*x?\s*y?\s*z?\s*
```

Как ни странно, под него попадают такие последовательности, как, например, "ace" или "bpxz". Как сделать, чтобы в выражении учитывались только последовательности без пропуска букв, типа "abcd", "opqr", "xy"?

**UPD**: забыл добавить, что пробелы игнорируются (для этого и испольльзую \s*). Регулярка должна в любом месте текста найти алфавитную последовательность. Например из фразы "перекличка дежурных" должно найтись "кл" и "деж" (на русском проще пример было придумать).

Comment: А вы на каком языке пишите и для чего это, может сделать другими средствами. Регулярочка жуткая выходит, другими средствами возможно проще ...

Comment: @Mike это скорее для sh

Comment: @Mike регулярка нужна для команды терминала grep.

Comment: @Daniil А perl на этой машине у вас есть (он есть на 90% машин где есть grep) ? И что в итоге работы надо сделать, т.е. если во входном файле строка "перекличка дежурных" что программа должна выдать на выходе. Я так понял, что подошедшие куски строки, только ли их или всю строку. Если только их то как их разделять

Comment: @Mike Надо написать команду для терминала, используя grep или sed. Она должна выводить только подошедшие куски из текстового файла (без разницы в строку или в столбик). Perl юзать нельзя. В принципе, решение, которое предложили ниже с подстрокой, подходит, но у меня не получается его реализовать.

Comment: `grep` с указанным параметром `-P` поддерживает регулярные выражения PCRE. Решение Mike вам подойдет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы к сожалению не указали какой диалект регулярных выражений можно использовать и для чего это надо. Возможно, есть более простые решения, основанные на специальных возможностях регулярных выражений или более простые средства без использования регулярок.

Для PCRE совместимого диалекта получается подобное выражение (до буквы d, продолжать по аналогии, пробелы поставить по вкусу):

```
(?:a(?=b))?(?:b(?=c))?(?:c(?=d))?(?:d(?=e))?
```

Тест на [ragex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/0W74IZ/1)

Из "Специальных возможностей" регулярных выражений можно, например, на языке `perl` проверку любых символов идущих подряд сделать так:

```
echo "abpade fg xyz" | perl -npe 's/.*?((?:([a-z])\s*(?=(??{chr(ord($2)+1)})))+.)/$1\n/g'

Результат:
ab
de fg
xyz
```

perl вполне можно использовать вместо grep на большинстве unix систем, записав требуемую команду в виде одной строки.

**UPD** Для командной строки, используя только grep и sed, короткий вариант:

```
echo "a bcefgkmoxyz" |\
grep -Po `echo -n 'bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' |\
sed 's/./\0\0/g;s/^/a/;s/\(.\)\(.\)/\\\\s*(?:\1(?=\\\\s*\2))?/g;s/.$/./'` |\
sed -n '/../p'

Результат:
a bc
efg
xyz
```

Команда разбита на несколько строк для удобства просмотра, можно в одну строку, убрав `\`. Мне было лень писать длиннющую регулярку, поэтому в качестве параметра `grep` передается результат выполнения (в обратных апострофах) команды `echo | sed` создающей нужное выражение на ходу из букв алфавита. К сожалению идеального выражения не получилось и grep выдает так же отдельные символы, для их подавления используется последняя строка `sed -n '/../p'`.

Параметр `grep` генерированный командами из алфавита выглядит так:

```
\\s*(?:a(?=\\s*b))?\\s*(?:b(?=\\s*c))?\\s*(?:c(?=\\s*d))?\\s*(?:d(?=\\s*e))?\\s*(?:e(?=\\s*f))?\\s*(?:f(?=\\s*g))?\\s*(?:g(?=\\s*h))?\\s*(?:h(?=\\s*i))?\\s*(?:i(?=\\s*j))?\\s*(?:j(?=\\s*k))?\\s*(?:k(?=\\s*l))?\\s*(?:l(?=\\s*m))?\\s*(?:m(?=\\s*n))?\\s*(?:n(?=\\s*o))?\\s*(?:o(?=\\s*p))?\\s*(?:p(?=\\s*q))?\\s*(?:q(?=\\s*r))?\\s*(?:r(?=\\s*s))?\\s*(?:s(?=\\s*t))?\\s*(?:t(?=\\s*u))?\\s*(?:u(?=\\s*v))?\\s*(?:v(?=\\s*w))?\\s*(?:w(?=\\s*x))?\\s*(?:x(?=\\s*y))?\\s*(?:y(?=\\s*z))?.
```

Answer (score 1):

Вообще можно было бы сделать строку "abcdef...xyz" и искать вашу строку как подстроку в этой строке. Обязателен regExp?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48703/discussion-on-answer-by-learp------).

Answer (score 1):

За каждой буквой обязана следовать следующая или конец строки:

```
a?\s*(?=b|$)
b?\s*(?=c|$)
...
y?\s*(?=z|$)
z?\s*$
```

Т. о. если буква есть, то она связана со следующей и пропуск не допускается.
Конкатенация таких регулярок даст желаемое выражение. Только крышку в начало добавить.

Answer (score 0):

Еще один вариант, тоже ограниченный от a до d, но захватывающий все символы. В одном из предложенных вариантов не захватывается последний символ последовательности.

```
(?(?=a)a(?=b))(?(?=b)b(?=c))(?(?=c)c(?=d))(?(?=d)d(?=e))
```

https://regex101.com/r/0W74IZ/2

---

Элегантное, но низкопроизводительное решение с модификацией обрабатываемого текста:

```
([a-z]{2,})(?=.*\1[a-z]*$)
```

Смысл очень прост: перед началом обработки текста в его конец нужно добавить всю последовательность:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Таким образом не нужно делать огромное регулярное выражение, достаточно в коде написать нечто вроде:

```
preg_match_all( $re, $text.$allLiteralOrderer, $result)
```

https://regex101.com/r/0W74IZ/3